# Error using Xen-server 6.2 "File System on Control Domain Full"

Tags: linux, xen, xenserver

I have been getting this error and i can't even upload new patches on the server.

- Is it wise to delete all the ".gz" logs on server from "/var/log"?

I have removed all the entries except the "/applied" folder from "/var/patch"

- Is there any solution on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The /var/log/ directory on the first server I checked was 100MB, so check if you've got an excess of logs first. I'd take a copy as well in case it helps you track down the cause. Deleting the .gz logs won't cause you any trouble though - I've done it many times.

They will come back of course, so you might have to keep an eye on them. Most of my servers at 6.2 level have several hundred MB available though, so you may have something else taking up space.
The times I've  come across this problem, there's normally a simple reason - someone trying to export a VM to /root for example. It's really a matter of finding the large directories (`du -shx /*`)and comparing to a server without the problem.

Comment: Tom Sparrow thank you,  I have monitored the server with deleted .gz log files, but the error came up again. I am not quite sure what's taking so much space in the server.

Comment: I have checked the directories with (du -shx /*) and here is an output.

5.4M        /bin
72M        /boot
1.5M      /cli-rt
164K     /dev
13M      /etc
28K      /EULA
4.0K     /home
435M     /lib
16K      /lost+found
4.0K     /media
4.0K     /mnt
1.6G     /opt
0         /proc
12K       /Read_Me_First.html
72K       /root
21M       /sbin
4.0K       /selinux
4.0K      /srv
0         /sys
1.6M     /tftpboot
136K     /tmp
587M    /usr
659M    /var

Comment: Your /opt looks much bigger than the 6.2 I have here - I'm only at 871M

Try `du -shx /opt/*` and see which part is grabbing so much space. Possibly something large you've installed. I have an APC directory for the UPS, but the single largest is 515M /opt/xensource

Comment: I think the problem is sorted but i will have to monitor the server.

I have done the following steps:

1. Remove additional Logs.

2. Remove cached uploaded patch files.

3. Remove the patch-backups.

4. Review additional files.


Remove additional Logs
 *  cd /var/log
 *  ls
 * remove the logs using # rm -f

Remove cached uploaded patch files
        * 
 cd /var/patch


* Remove all the entries except the "/applied" folder

Remove the patch-backups
* cd /opt/xensource/patch-backup
* ls
* rm -rf *

Remove stunnel entries
* # cd /tmp/